# Having more than 3 items in genlist?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm trying to realize/display more than 3 items in a Genlist on Tizen 5 wearable (circular).

Tried:

- creating custom item style (setting min/max values)
- overriding `1text` style with my own content

But everytime the genlist has exactly 3 items.

**Bonus solution: how to keep the `1text` style while having more than 3 items?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the item size is smaller than 1text, it could show more items.
but for this, text font size also need to be smaller than 1text I think.

about bonus question,
1text style size cannot changed unless you copy every detalis of that style and change the text or padding size.